# Preferred way to direct user's domain names to my web app?

Tags: iis, web-applications, dns, url-routing

Background context: ASP.NET / IIS (not sure if it matters)

I have a web app at **example.com**, and a user of my app gets his own content page at an address like **example.com/abc-trinkets**. I would like to offer the user the ability to point his own registered domain at my web app so his content is accessed at **abctrinkets.com**. Initially looking on the order of 10-100 users with custom domains.

Ideally, I would like my user to just have a single hostname or IP address that he needs to know to configure properly with his registrar, and if I change the setup of my servers (different host, change addresses, load balancing, etc.) the user will not have to change his settings.

I have no trouble handling the requests once they hit my web app, but I am looking for input on the best way to set the routing up so requests actually come to my app/server. *I would like a "catch-all" type of behavior that does not require me to individually configure anything for each domain a user might point to me.*

I assume I will need some kind of layer between the address I give my user and my actual server ... is this like a managed DNS service or some other type of nameserver thing I would set up with my host? Is this something simple that should already be handled by a few simple settings on my webserver? I worry that I am making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Note that you change the setup of your servers to a different IP address, your users will always have to reconfigure properly with their DNS registrar. [Unless you still own the old IP addresses and reroute from there, that is.]

Comment: tiagoinu, this was really what I was intending to ask, I guess ... is there some way I can add a layer in between so that user points his domain to address X, and X is a service which resolves his request and sends it to my server Y, and the user doesn't need to know Y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a script that examines the `Host` header in the request. In your example, if it's `abctrinkets.com`, then you'd either redirect or forward the request to `/abc-trinkets`. You'd still need a database or something for mapping the domain names to the URLs; if you're going to allow arbitrary domain names for each user account, then there's no possible way to avoid that.

Comment: Appreciate the response, but I'm actually talking about the step BEFORE that, as in, how to make sure requests for *abctrinkets.com* will come to my server. I updated the question title to clarify (I hope)

Comment: @babtek If the userdomain.com is already pointing to your ip address, there's not else you need to do, except maybe configuring IIS to accept and serve all requests independently of the Host header.

Comment: I am accepting this answer as it was proper guidance, and I just butchered the question-asking process. I gotta work on my phrasing skills =)